# DropDownList - Get custom property of selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a custom class which has been bound to Dropdownlist.

```
public class RoleIdSelection
    {
        public string RoleID { get; set; }
        public string RoleDesc { get; set; }
        public string OrgCode { get; set; }
        public string OrgName { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }


List<RoleIdSelection> lstRoles = new List<RoleIdSelection>();
ddlUserProfile.DataSource = lstRoles;
ddlUserProfile.DataTextField = "RoleDesc";
ddlUserProfile.DataValueField = "RoleId";
ddlUserProfile.DataBind();
```

How do i get the properties from selected item? i have tried

```
RoleIdSelection rid = ddlUserProfile.SelectedItem as RoleIdSelection;
```

but it shows warning

> Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to
>   'RoleIdSelection' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion,
>   unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either repopulate the List of RoleIdSelection and then use the selected value to get the RoleIdSelection or you can serialize the list of RoleIdSelection and save it in a hidden field to retrieve on post back. The latter of the two options opens you up to manipulation by the client.

Here is the first option

```
//repopulate the List<RoleIdSelection>
List<RoleIdSelection> roles = GetTheRoles();

RoleIdSelection role = roles.First(r => r.RoleID==ddlUserProfile.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Now role has the correct RoleIdSelection

Comment: quite manipulative. It will save me for the time being. But why asp.net doesn't support this fuctinaltiy. I recollect that i was able do it easily in winforms.

Comment: @user2564977 Because the web is by its very nature stateless. The bound data would have to be saved in ViewState which would go to the client. Not necessarily something you want to do because of page size and security concerns. So instead of directly getting the selected item, you get the ID of the bound item and then pull that information back out of wherever you saved it (database, Session, View State, etc).